# Probability - Dice Toss

Tags: probability

When rolling two dice, what is the probability that the roll will be $5$, $2$ on two consecutive rolls? I'm pretty sure it's $\frac{2}{36}$ for one roll, but I'm not sure how to figure the second. The answer in the book says it's $\frac{1}{36}$, but I can't figure out how it works.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If the order does not matter (i.e., $52$ and $25$ are the same), then the answer is $(\frac{2}{36})^2$. Are you sure that's the exact question? Perhaps the dice are tossed more than twice?

Comment: I misunderstood the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because its two consecutive rolls , it takes place one after the other.. so, prob to get either 5 or 2 in first roll is (2/36) and prob to get either 5 or 2 in secd roll is (2/36). so the total prob will be 4/36=1/9.. so my answer is 1/9.

Comment: You misinterpreted the question, which is what is the probability of obtaining a 5 on the first roll followed by a 2 on the second roll?

Comment: That's what I did.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you quoted the question **exactly** ?

My hunch is that the question was asking :

**When rolling a die twice**, what is the probability of getting 5,2.

The book answer would then be correct, Pr = $\dfrac16\times\dfrac16 = \dfrac{1}{36}$

Comment: This is like mathematical Jeopardy lol.

Comment: I misunderstood the question.  Thanks for clearing it up, and for the quick response.

Comment: you're welcome :)